# Doom Emacs not inserting citep references into LaTeX document

Tags: latex, doom, org-ref

I'm new to using LaTeX for writing papers and I'm trying to get a workflow going using LaTeX in Doom Emacs on Arch Linux (all the required texlive packages having first been installed via pacman). However I cannot get LaTeX to render 'citep:' entries - at all!.  I want to tangle references as I write and insert them into the thesis as and when I need to.  So I'm experimenting with the following dummy org document:

```
#+TITLE: Workflow Sample
#+PROPERTY: header-args :exports none :tangle "~/Documents/org/bibliography/HAD/references.bib"
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [12pt]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[natbib=true]{biblatex} \DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1} \addbibresource{~/Documents/org/bibliography/HAD/references.bib}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{parskip}
#+OPTIONS: <:nil c:nil todo:nil H:5
* Generative Methods
** Probability
*** Basic probabilistic methods as a path to musical variation citep:temp2007ElementaryProbability
#+begin_src bibtex
@book{temp2007ElementaryProbability,
title = {Elementary Probability},
author = {Temperley D.},
booktitle = {Music and Probability},
keywords = {probability, probabilistic methods},
year = {2007},
}
#+end_src
There are several basic concepts that are useful to know when thinking about the relationship between probability and musical variation.
Three of the most important ones are: the probability function, the distribution, and joint probability citep:temp2007ElementaryProbability.
* References
:PROPERTIES:
:UNNUMBERED: t
:END:
#+LaTeX: \printbibliography[heading=none]
```

The above template tangles the natbib entry to the references.bib file OK. It also generates a .tex file with the correct \citep{temp2007DElementaryProbability} entry as expected and a PDF. This would suggest that LaTeX with natbib is working OK. Nevertheless in the PDF output 'citep:temp2007ElementaryProbability' is quoted literally and is not interpreted. Am I missing some configuration in Emacs to get the citep directive to work or what? Any suggestion as to how to solve this issue would be great as it is driving me v-e-r-y s-l-o-w-l-y nuts. Thx in advance...

Comment: That is an org-ref citep link. Do you have org-ref installed and loaded?

Comment: Hi John. Yes I do with the 'org-ref-default-bibliography' and 'org-ref-pdf-directory' paths correctly set in config.el. If I click on the citep link in the org document I get the Citation menu in emacs with available references displayed so paths are good. I've played with things a bit since posting the question. I have replaced \usepackage[natbib=true]{biblatex} with [round]{natbib} to see if that works but I am now, instead of getting the citep entry displayed literally, I'm getting question marks where each reference should be.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a conflict with the default packages you use in org-mode, probably natbib. Try building your file like this:

```
(let ((org-latex-default-packages-alist nil)
      (org-latex-pdf-process '("latexmk -f -pdf -%latex -bibtex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=%o %f")))
  (org-open-file (org-latex-export-to-pdf)))
```

In this example, I use a no-default package setup.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkitchin/org-ref/master/examples/biblatex-example.org

Comment: Sounds reasonable John. U mean like in line 4 of my example?

Comment: I'll take a closer look at your model :)

Comment: you are right, I didn't see that line 4 at the end. see the updated answer for a probable reason it is not working for you.

Comment: Thx for reply John. Unfortunately the setting 'org-latex-default-packages-alist nil' has resulted in no PDF being generated at all. I've had to reload the entire OS-twice since I was enable to reverse this!. I'm at a complete loss as to why clicking on a citep link  brings up the Citations Actions menu which in turn displays all  the available references in the .bib file as expected but when the PDF is generated the links cant be found. I'm wondering precisely what     package or bit of functionality resolves the link in the PDF?

Comment: you should try building your pdf manually from the latex file, it will tell you what the problem is. Clicking and exporting are unrelated, and your problem is certainly on the LaTeX side. If you use the code above, there is no way it should result in something that has to be undone, that is a temporary modification of the variables.

Comment: Thx John. I did as you suggested. Running pdflatex on the *.tex file generated by emacs told me to run biber as no *.bbl file existed along with other stuff. After doing that and then running pdflatex on the *.tex file again the references appeared in the document. I was unaware that running biber was required as an intermediate step. I want to accept your original answer but it was your suggestion to build the pdf manually that did the trick!

Comment: the org-latex-pdf-process command above should have taken care of running biber I think. did you try that code?

Comment: Yes I did. I've given it a shot twice. Unfortunately evaluating that code did not work. I'm fairly new to emacs so I might be doing something wrong. Not to worry; I simply execute the C-c C-e o l keychain on the org file followed by the pdflatex-biber-pdflatex sequence in the terminal which I've linked to an alias and all is good. Thanks for your help anyways... .